# Is my relay working properly?

Tags: arduino, voltage, relay, 5v

I have 4 relay module originally created for Arduino (it looks very close to the image below) and I am little confused with the way how it works.

[image]

There are 6 pins ins this relay:

- GND
- IN1
- IN2
- IN3
- IN4
- VCC

So when i connect 5V to VCC and ground to GND - I get about 3V between each of the IN1..IN4 and GND. Why does it happen?

Comment: Wait, are these guys really isolating relay coils with opto-couplers?  Someone needs to tell them that relays already isolate.  This looks like a design based on religious beliefs.

Comment: How about a link to the original module?

Comment: I only know what is written over it - "4 Relay Module".

Comment: @OlinLathrop  I too am wondering why people (not just these folks) opto-coulpe relay coils.  My best guess is that this is done to prevent the spike from the relay coil from propagating to the microcontroller.

Comment: @OlinLathrop That type of relay in particular actually provides rather poor coil-contact isolation. The optos work quite well unless a hapless user deliberately bypasses them to use a common power supply, in which case they may have to go on an EMI hunt.

Comment: @NickAlexeev It's not the coil, it's contact-coil capacitance that couples hundreds-of-volts at maybe 1MHz noise from the contacts back to the driving MCU. If cost is no object and you have a multilayer board with ground planes you can probably get away without isolation. Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Inputs are active low. The inputs are VCC to a resistor, the optó led and a regular led. When pulled low, the optó coupler turns on, turning the relay transistor and the relay on. When left floating you will measure a voltage of VCC - the forward voltage drop of the leds. That's normal.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I could catch only that this is normal) So as it is normal - I shouldn't damage Arduino's pins or  Raspberry Pi's GPIO if I connect one of those pins to IN1...IN4?

Comment: This will not damage the RPi or the Arduino.As the RPI has 3v3 and 5v for Arduino.